# Google Analytics API - how do I get access tokens without being an Admin

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm very new to using APIs and I'm struggling to figure out the authentication. With my email I can log in to a corporate analytics page and view the information. My account is only at a 'user' level. How do I get access tokens so I can scrape the data from the page using the Google API? Do I need the admins of the page to get these tokens? I tried using the generate access token but I don't know the service account email. Any advice would be appreciated because I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer:  how do I get access tokens without being an Admin

As long as your personal account has read access you can use Oauht2 to authorize your application and then be able to access the data that way you do not need to be admin.

## All your other questions

> How do I get access tokens so I can scrape the data from the page using the Google API?

First off if you use Oauth2 in your application and login with your own user you you will be able to use the Google Analytics api as you have read access thats all you need for the Google analytics api in order to request data.

> Do I need the admins of the page to get these tokens?

No anyone with read access can authorize an application to access the google analytics api.

> I tried using the generate access token but I don't know the service account email.

Service accounts are completely different than normal Oauth2.  A service account is a dummy user which needs to be preauthorized to access the data it has nothing to do with your personal access.  To preauthorize a service account to access the google analytics api you will need to have admin access to the google analytics account and take the service ac count email address and add it as a user on the google analytics account.  It will then have access to read the data.

> Any advice would be appreciated because I'm so confused.

Decide if your application should be allowing users to login to it and access the data on their own google analytics accounts.  If so then you should be using Oauth2 and not a service account.

If you are only trying to access this single google analytics account then you should be using a service account.  However you will need to contact the admin to have them grant your service account access to the data.